# Java pupils enrollment system

Tags: java

I have to design a small after school clubs management system with GUI (which has been designed at the beginnning). The system should perform a few functions:
- add a pupil,
- add a club,
- add a pupil to a specified club.
When user clicks on a club, it should list all of the pupils enrolled in the club. On the other hand, it should list all of the clubs the student is enrolled in when user clicks on a pupil. 
The first two functions are done and work properly. However, I'm struggling with adding a pupil to a specified club.

Comment: When you say *database* do you mean `ArrayList`?

Comment: @art1210 perhaps you can post a bit more code.  For example, where is this `addPupilToClub` method living and where is `newList` coming from?

Comment: @art1210 Curious, is the type of `pupilsInClub` really given as `List<List<String>>`?  Seems it should be more `List<List<Club>>` in order to be able to test whether a `Pupil` belongs to a `Club`.

Comment: @art1210 Derp moment, actually should be `List<Club>` since each `Club` contains a `List<Pupil>`... which lends nicely to 1) check whether a Pupil belongs a Club, and 2) dump out a list of each Club's Pupils

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given criteria,

> A given comment on that method is: (1) The club and (2) the pupil must already have been added to the database and (3) the pupil must not have been previously added to club. If these conditions are not met then the method should do nothing and return false. If they are met then the pupil is added to the club and the method returns true .

```
public boolean addPupilToClub(String clubName, String firstName, String lastName) {
    String studentID = firstName + " " + lastName;
    if (clubs.indexOf(clubName) == -1   // (1) the clubName  does not exist
        || pupils.indexOf(studentID) == -1)  // (2) OR the pupil does not exist {
          return false;
    } 

    //the rest is pseudo code

    else if (<<(3) the specified club already contains the student>>) {
          return false;
    } else { 
      //student never added to the club before
          <<insert code that adds student to club>>

          //additional check whether club is already included in master list (say, pupilsInClub?)
          //if not, add club to master list

          return true;
    }
}
```

Ideally, if you want to print out a list of Clubs and its Pupils, there should be a master list of Clubs (containing Pupils), say `pupilsInClub`, of type  `List<Club>`.  Then you can iterate over `pupilsInClub` and for each Club, utilize some method in class `Club` to dump out its Pupils.

Note: you would also have to make sure a Club `A` hasn't already been added to `pupilsInClub`.  If Club A already exists in `pupilsInClub`, simply add the new Pupil to Club A.  Otherwise, you will also have to add Club A to `pupilsInClub`.

Comment: @art1210 One difficulty I see though is, if the list of Clubs is of type `List<String>` and not of type `List<Club>`, how will you check for the membership of a pupil? (Condition #3)... may want to rethink the types of `clubs` and `pupils` in class `AfterSchoolBase`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably maintain a list of `Pupil` inside the `Club` class. So inside the `Club`:

```
private List<Pupil> pupils;
```

And a method to add `Pupil` to this list:

```
public void addPupil(Pupil p) {
    pupils.add(p);
}
```

And in the `addPupilToClub` method this is how you add a `Pupil` to a `Club`:

```
Club c = new Club(clubName);
Pupil p = new Pupil(firstName, lastName);
c.addPupil(p);
```

Do remember to initialize `pupils`, inside the `Club` constructor maybe.

Comment: And I think a `Set` rather than a `List`, but it's not clear if that's also forbidden by the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing yourself by using such a large `if` condition in `addPupilToClub`.  Breaking it up into nested statements will allow you to comment each one:

```
public boolean addPupilToClub(String clubName, String firstName, String lastName) {
    if (clubs.indexOf(clubName) != -1) {   // the clubName exists
        if (pupils.indexOf(firstName + " " + lastName) != -1) { // the pupil exists
            if (newList.indexOf(firstName + " " + lastName)==-1)) {  // the pupil isn't in newList
                Club c=new Club(clubName);
                Pupil p = new Pupil(firstName,lastName);
                newList.add(p.getFullName());
                pupilsInClub.add(newList);
                removeDuplicates();
                System.out.println(pupilsInClub);
```

Once we do this, I think it's easier to see that you're creating a new club and a new pupil after you discover that the club and pupil already exist.  That looks like a mistake.